# Как сделать так, чтобы телеграм-бот давал ответ?

Tags: python, telebot

Друзья, никак не могу понять как написать функцию, чтобы из чата (CHAT_ID) прилетал ответ обратно пользователю, от которого бот переслал фото. Прошу помощи! Заранее спасибо!

Вот скелет кода:

````
import telebot

bot_token = 'my token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token) 
CHAT_ID = my id

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f' Hi, {message.from_user.first_name}')


@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['photo', 'document'])
def get_photo_messages(message):
    
    bot.forward_message(CHAT_ID,
    message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, f'Photo from {message.from_user.first_name}: @{message.from_user.username}')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'✔️Thank You!')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f' I Dont take text, sorry!')

# Function answer on CHAT_ID for user


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0) ```
````